# How can I convert a "String HH:MM" to a "int hour HH" and "int minute MM"

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have this code. And I need convert a `string` **"horaTarefa HH:MM"** to `int` **"hour = HH"** and `int` **"minute = MM"**

I guess can I do the same thing with **"dateTarefa DD/MM/YYYY"**?

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("AgendadorTarefas.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null); { }

Cursor c = db.query("Tarefa", new String[] {
              "codTarefa", "dateTarefa", "horaTarefa", "textoTarefa"}, 
            null, null, null, null, null);

c.moveToFirst();

final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

while(c.moveToNext())
{ 
    String Date = c.getString(1);
    String Hora = c.getString(2);
    String Texto = c.getString(3);
    result.add(Data + " às " + Hora + " \n" + Texto);
}

hour = Calendar.HOUR;
minute = Calendar.MINUTE;

c.close();
```

Comment: Please consider using the proper name convention for Java (like lowerCamelCase variable names, in this case). This really improves the readability of your code, especially with the SO highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the position of the hour/minute/etc and it is always the same, you can get it with `substring`, and then convert it to numbers with `Integer.parseInt`

```
String Hora = "12:34";
int hour = Integer.parseInt(Hora.substring(0, 2));
int minute = Integer.parseInt(Hora.substring(3));

String Date = "12/34/5678";
int day = Integer.parseInt(Date.substring(0, 2));
int month = Integer.parseInt(Date.substring(3, 5));
int year = Integer.parseInt(Date.substring(6));
```

Answer (score 7):

It's better to use a dateformatter instead of just parsing integers. This way you have much more control over what the time and date can look like (are one-digit numbers written as *05* or *5*? Is the time 12-hour or 24-hour format? ...)

A simple code to parse a time could look like:

```
try
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("H:m");
    Date date = format.parse("15:34");
    int hours = date.getHours(); 
    int min   = date.getMinutes();
}
catch (ParseException e)
{
    // parsing failed
}
```

For a reference of what the format parameters can look like take a look at the [SimpleDateFormat Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

If you really want to make your application international, you should also consider using [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead of just Date as I did in the example.

Comment: date.getHours() is deprecated. Use Calendar instance.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

**date.getHours() is deprecated** so i choose to updated answer for this question by using Calendar and best answer of this question.

```
public static int getHour(String hourString) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(hourString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return Integer.parseInt(hourString.substring(0, 2));
    }
}
```